How can I parse multiple subsequent YAML files in a C program using libyaml?
I'm writing a C program wherein multiple YAML configuration files need to be parsed at startup. Initially, I just made it work with a single file to start out simple, but now that I'm changing it to parse all available configuration files, I encountered a problem where if I just set a new input file with yaml_parser_set_input_file(), I hit an assertion  where it tells me that I can only set the source once. So what gives? How can I parse multiple files?

You could try using freopen.

I worked around this limitation by just initialising and then deleting the parser for every input file. Something like this:
#include <yaml.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    yaml_parser_t parser;

    // Initial setup logic

    while (files_to_process) {
        yaml_parser_initialize(&parser);
        yaml_parser_set_input_file(&parser, input);

        while (events_to_parse) {
            // Event processing logic
        }

        yaml_parser_delete(&parser);
    }        
}

This works for me. It feels like it should be possible to do this in a nicer way, but I couldn't find one.

Presumably, it would also work to just set up and use an entirely separate yaml_parser_t object for each input.  The libyaml documentation isn't very clear about this, but its parser objects do store document-specific data. It's reasonable (though not inevitable) that you need to re-initialize in order to switch to a different input.

That's effectively what the run-parser test from the testsuite does.
